# Update Column Table Based on Date and Time in the table column

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I just wanna ask how to update a specific column with date and time. I have a table column named date,time and dayofstay

ex.

```
|dayofstay|       date        |         time.       |
|        1       |09/06/2017  |6:30:27.10273
```

If the system time ticks at 6:30:27.10273
At ahead of date 09/06/2017 it will calculate the totaldays from date column to sysdate()
Then the totaldays will be updated to dayofstay column.
ex if

the system date and time ticks at 09/07/2017,6:30:27.10273 it will calculate the total days the update the table like this

```
|dayofstay|       date        |         time.       |
|      2         |09/06/2017  |6:30:27.10273|
```

any ideas about this I search it's a trigger
But I am lack of knowledge in SQL.
Ideas, little code to figure it out or advices is
accepted

Comment: I would advise against it. No point of storing data you can easily calculate on select.

Comment: Maybe Comparing the system date and column date to get the totalday and update it?

Comment: Or need to manually update it?

Comment: I agree with @ZoharPeled. Storing this is kind of silly. You always want it to relative tothe current time, calculate it in your select statement. If you store this it is always incorrect in the table.

Comment: What does the word "ticks" even mean in this context?   What are you talking about when you say "if the system date and time ticks at ..."?

Comment: What I mean at 'ticks' every time 6:30:27.10273 on the other day it will calculate the DiffDate of date and system date and update the dayofstay table

Answer (score 0):

```
WHILE EXISTS(SELECT DaysofStay from AdmittedPatientWard where [Status] = 'ADMITTED' AND LastTimeCensus <= CONVERT (time, SYSDATETIME()))
BEGIN
UPDATE [dbo].[AdmittedPatientWard]
   SET  [DaysofStay] = DATEDIFF ( D , AdmittedPatientWard.LastCensusDate , GETDATE() )

 WHERE [Status] = 'ADMITTED'
END
```

I came up with this code